# input tag with preset value="999" fails to be inserted to MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, html, database, forms, input

I have two text inputs and I am trying to insert their values into my SQL database, but for some reason when i preset the input tags with any value ( numeric or alphabetical ) my '$_POST' if statements fail to pick them up on the next page.

```
<form action="select-process2.php" method="post" name="phoneselect">  

<td><input name="B1-Name" maxlength="40" type="text" value="999" disabled="disabled"/></td>
<td><input name="B1-Target" maxlength="15" type="text" value="999" disabled="disabled"/></td>

</form>
```

select_process2.php is where I try and capture the posted values from my form, the code for which is below:

```
        if (isset($_POST['B1-Name']))
            { $B1name = $_POST['B1-Name'];

                if (isset($_POST['B1-Target']))
                { $B1target = $_POST['B1-Target'];
    }
}

echo "$B1name<br />";
echo "$B1target<br />";
```

Its at this point that I would normally see the passed  values of my inputs, however if they have the reset value="999" like in the earlier code block it simply fails and I can't see why, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields are `disabled` so they won't be included in the submitted data.

You might be looking for `readonly` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I swapped out the     disabled for     readonly and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You also have both inputs disabled.  When `disabled='disabled'` is included in an `<input>`, many browsers will neglect to send the value to the server in the POST at all.

[See the w3c documentation on disabling inputs.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1). Specifically:

> In this example, the INPUT element is disabled. Therefore, it cannot receive user input nor will its value be submitted with the form.